# Phonegap + SSL + iPhone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, ssl

I'm developing an app for Android, iOS and Windows Phone that has SSL authentication with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. It's a great combo for mobile development.

I have a valid GoDaddy certificate installed on my REST API server and in both Android and Windows Phone it works just fine.

On iOS, when I try to login, it's raised an exception "NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)".

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the certificate needed to be installed on the server with it's trust chain, not only the certificate itself. Problem solved.